# Render function on input removes reactivity in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create a render function which renders an `input` field in Vue.

I can do this easily in a normal `vue` file with templates like so:

```
// NormalInput.vue
<template>
  <input :value="value" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "NormalInput",
  props: {
    value: null
  }
};
</script>
```

*Note that the above does indeed work correctly.*

But when trying to convert the above code into a render function with the following code:

```
// RenderFunctionInput.js
export default {
  name: "RenderFunctionInput",
  props: {
    value: null
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("input", {
      attrs: { value: this.value }
    });
  }
};
```

It seems reactive at first, but after editing the `RenderFunctionInput` manually, it stops being reactive. The Vue data seems to be updating but the actual value of the input does not.

You can view an example at https://codesandbox.io/embed/oooq7o2q16?module=%2Fsrc%2FApp.vue

---

**Example screenshots:**

I've created an example of the two components mentioned above. They are both using the same data value which is being incremented by `1` every 100 ms.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

After typing in the `NormalInput`, it instantly gets overwritten by the `:value="val"` data. But when typing in the `RenderFunctionInput`, it stops incrementing and becomes detached from the data and becomes unreactive.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `attrs` in the render function, you should use `domProps`.

> As soon as the content of the input is edited, the attribute's value
>   is still updated in the DOM (you can check your console) but that
>   attribute is no longer relevant to what is being displayed

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9027#issuecomment-435797509

---

The render function should look like this instead:

```
// RenderFunctionInput.js
export default {
  name: "RenderFunctionInput",
  props: {
    value: null
  },
  render(createElement) {
    return createElement("input", {
      domProps: { value: this.value }
    });
  }
};
```